# want to consume WSDL web service in C# client without App.config(but via code)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I want to consume a WSDL webservice in a C# class library project without changing the `app.config` file. I am having restrictions to alter the `app.config` with some third party platform where I have to upload DLL only.
After adding service reference my `app.config` looks like:

```
<configuration> 
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="xxxxxAPIPortBinding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>               
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://xxxxxxx.com:443/xxxxxAPI"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxxxxAPIPortBinding"
                contract="xxxxxAPI.xxxxxAPI" name="xxxxxAPIPort" />            
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

How can I consume the webservice for above configuration in C# class?

I have tried following approach:

```
HttpsTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement() { MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue, MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue };

TextMessageEncodingBindingElement TextMessage = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement() { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12 };

CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(TextMessage, httpTransport);

ChannelFactory<IMyService>  channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(customBinding);
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("https://xxxxxxxxx.com:443/AnyService?wsdl");

IMyService serviceObj = channelFactory.CreateChannel(ep);

string uuid = serviceObj.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

But got error

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {http://tempuri.org/}login

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

Comment: Check the msdn doc on the WCF customBinding, there is a sample code that declares it from scratch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.custombinding?view=netframework-4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
// usings:
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

void ConsumeWebService()
{
    var myBinding = new CustomBinding("xxxxxAPIPortBinding");

    // Manually define Endpoint:
    //var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/myservice");

    // Or get from configuration file:
    ClientSection clientSection = (ClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
    ChannelEndpointElement myEndpoint = clientSection.Endpoints[0];

    // Define a communication channel, based on the interface, bindig e endpoint
    var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<xxxxxAPI.PlunetAPI>(myBinding, myEndpoint.Address.AbsoluteUri);
    xxxxxAPI.PlunetAPIclient client = null;

    try
    {
        // Create the channel to consume the service
        client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        client.MyMethod();  //Calls some method
        ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
        }
    }
}
```